# NetSuite - post multi-currency bills to COA

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We have a chart of account, say "34000 (Sweden)" that has been setup with a currency being SEK. On raising a vendor bill that is in USD, we are unable to select account 34000 as the 'Account' field on the expense line item.

How can we override this as we need to be able to post multi-currency bills to that account?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using `multi-book accounting` where you can post transactions to multiple books with different currencies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Have you used multi-book accounting and would it require a new COA setup?

Comment: haven't used it. This feature requires additional license cost. But, there is sufficient information in help to configure it.